# Android - ImageView below recyclerView sticked to bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I have a RelativeLayout, inside one image on top, below Recyclerview, and below the Recyclerview I want to have an ImageView, but aligned to the bottom of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/recyclerview1">

          <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/deco"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

However, the image at the bottom appears only when there are no items in Recyclerview, otherwise the Image is not showing, the list is scrolling to the bottom of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it by adding a LinearLayput wrapper to recyclerview and adding some bottom margin.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

          <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/deco"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```